# Downloading Planet data using API

Tags: python, download, planet

I am following the method as shown in the Python notebook [here](https://github.com/planetlabs/notebooks/blob/master/jupyter-notebooks/data-api-tutorials/search_and_download_quickstart.ipynb) to download Planet satellite data from their API.

But, I am getting an error after I run the following piece of code:

```
import os
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# API Key stored as an env variable
PLANET_API_KEY = os.getenv('PL_API_KEY')

item_type = "PSScene4Band"

# API request object
search_request = {
  "interval": "day",
  "item_types": [item_type], 
  "filter": combined_filter
}

# fire off the POST request
search_result = \
  requests.post(
    'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/quick-search',
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''),
    json=search_request)

print(json.dumps(search_result.json(), indent=1))
```

Error:

```
{
 "message": "Please enter your API key.",
 "errors": []
}
```

I checked for the API key by doing `echo $PL_API_KEY` and it produced the correct API key.

How can I figure this out so that I can download data from Planet API?

Comment: I'm not a Planet user, but perhaps you need to include the API key as a URL parameter; it's not really basic auth (which should be user/password). A quick scan of the documentation suggests you should be using an `Authorization` header, with a value like `api-key {your-api-key}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you verified your API-key is valid and active?  It could be done either [with Planet Explorer](https://www.planet.com/explorer/)
or  in [your Planet account](https://www.planet.com/account/).

The [API documentation](https://developers.planet.com/quickstart/apis/) or [this example](https://github.com/planetlabs/notebooks/blob/master/jupyter-notebooks/data-api-tutorials/planet_data_api_introduction.ipynb) of a Jupyter notebook with Python should help you.

Comment: Yes. I verified the KEY by echo $PL_API_KEY.

Comment: Do it in python; just before the `# fire off the POST request` line add a line with `print(PLANET_API_KEY)` to see what the python variable contains

Comment: A very relevant documentation page would be https://developers.planet.com/docs/apis/data/api-mechanics/ , try the code there and see if your API key works at all